# ECS task Failed With couchbase database

Tags: nestjs, amazon-ecs, couchbase

I am using ECS service of AWS.
I am using nest js application.
We have couchbase database which is installed in EC2 instance.
At the time of server up we fetch full data from couchbase by use of N1QL query.

whenever i create task of ECS it will converted into Deprovisioning status.

I added error message which is available in my docker container logs of ECS tasks.

```
FATAL ERROR:
    libcouchbase experienced an unrecoverable error and terminates the program
    to avoid undefined behavior.
    The program should have generated a "corefile" which may used
    to gather more information about the problem.
    If your system doesn't create "corefiles" I can tell you that the
    assertion failed in ../deps/lcb/src/mcserver/negotiate.cc at line 50
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If anyone has idea about it how to resolved it then please comment here.

Thanks!!

How can i solved this issue?

Below is my connection code for query.

```
export class CouchbaseService implements OnModuleInit {
    private cluster: Cluster;
    private bucket: Bucket;
    private collection: Collection;
    private isInit: boolean = false;
    cols: Map<string, CollectionHelper> = new Map();

    constructor(
        private readonly configService: ConfigService,
        @InjectSentry() private readonly sentry: SentryService,
    ) {}

    async onModuleInit(): Promise<void> {
        await this.connect();
    }

    async connect() {
        // Make connection
        this.cluster = await connect(this.configService.get('couchbase.url'), {
            username: this.configService.get<string>('couchbase.username'),
            password: this.configService.get<string>('couchbase.password'),
        });
        // Initialise bucket
        this.bucket = this.cluster.bucket(
            this.configService.get<string>('couchbase.bucket'),
        );
        this.collection = this.bucket.defaultCollection();
        this.isInit = true;
        console.log('COUCHBASE INITIATED');
    }

    query<T>(query: string, options?: QueryOptions) {
        return this.handleErrors(async () => {
            try {
                const result = await this.cluster.query(query, options);
                return result?.rows ? result?.rows : [];
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('N1QL ERROR: ', e);
                return [];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "full data", what does that mean? What versions of Couchbase Server are you using? What version of the Couchbase node SDK? Can you post the code sample where this error occurs?

Comment: At the time of server up we are fetching aroud 3000-4000 document from couchbase using N1QL query.
for node i used couchbase:3.2.5 package version
couchbase version is Community Edition 7.1.0

Comment: @MatthewGroves code sample is edited in main question

Comment: One more thing to try if you can, is to run SDK Doctor: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/sdk/sdk-doctor.html - that will help identify any network/connectivity isssues

Comment: try using the latest nodejs SDK which is 4.2.9
https://docs.couchbase.com/nodejs-sdk/current/project-docs/sdk-release-notes.html

Comment: Also - make sure to reuse the cluster.  i.e. your application should call connect() only once.

The issue you should see was fixed in either either JSCBC-881 or JSCBC-884.